# Alert with UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is it possible to do something like what is shown below using an Alert with a UITableView? If so, how can it be done?

[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please rephrase.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your question. Are you asking how to do something like what is shown in the image?

Comment: I think he wants to customize the UIAlertView and it should look like the attached screen..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

read my this post - http://www.makebetterthings.com/blogs/iphone/add-uitextfield-in-uialertview/

and try to add a table or scroll view instead of uitextfield

Comment: i have a problem in CGRectMake do you can help me ?!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5704284/problem-in-cgrectmake-for-tableview-in-alertview

Answer (score -1):

No, that's not a UITableView. If you want to show something like that, use UIAlertView:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Annuler" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil]; [alert show]; [alert release];
```

Comment: i know is a AlertView but i want to do samething like this a Alert View with TableView