# Problem in CGRectMake for TAbleView in AlertView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
[textInfo resignFirstResponder];
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
informationTableView *informationtableView = [[informationTableView alloc]  initWithNibName:@"informationTableView"bundle:nil]; 
 UIView* MyView = informationtableView.view;
MyView.frame = CGRectMake(12.0f, 35.0f, 260.0f, 56.0f); 

[self.view addSubview:MyView];

UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Choisir" message:@"this gets coveredthis gets coveredthis gets coveredthis gets coveredthis gets coveredthis gets coveredthis gets coveredthis gets coveredthis gets coveredthis gets coveredthis gets coveredthis gets covered" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
[myAlertView addSubview:MyView];
[myAlertView show];
[myAlertView release];
```

}

[image: The problem TableView can not control the frame i like to get a tableView in this Alert]

The problem is that the TableView is not controled by the frame. I'd like to get the tableView inside the Alert. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this:

```
 UIView* MyView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:  CGRectMake(12.0f, 35.0f, 260.0f, 56.0f)];
 MyView.clipToBound = YES; //this ensures that the subviews are clipped by the view's frame
 [MyView addSubview:informationtableView.view];
 [self.view addSubview:MyView];
```

Comment: In general your solution is correct, but in this case (adding a tableView to a UIAlertView), it is merely doing a really bad thing in the "correct" way, sort of like making sure your shoes are shined and your socks match before shooting yourself in the foot :-)

Comment: Maybe you should read his answer, his idea is a UIActionSheet. And this is the only way this should be implemented. The subview in a UIAlertView approaches will all fail in the future. They failed already when iOS4 came out. And they will fail again in the future. Imagine apple decides to make the UIAlertView taller, wider or they decide to increase the font size by one pt.

Comment: re: analogies - I think there's an app for that, but sadly for me, no badge for that :)

Answer (score 1):

A) I don't think the UIAlert is going to behave well with a tablView inside of it. You're asking for trouble.
B) I think you want to use a UIActionSheet, which is designed to show the user an array of choices.